# Load chrome profile in python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

i try to load a chrome profile in python selenium. I can load to the profile but it stuck at the new tab, don't access to the website i want. Anything wrong with my code?

```
import time
import undetected_chromedriver as uc

options = uc.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\hungs\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data")
options.add_argument("--profile-directory=Profile 1")
options.add_argument("--incognito")
driver = uc.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get('https://www.google.com')
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have a Chrome profile having some website session (let's say Instagram) that you would like to open/load.

Here's how you can achieve it.

```py
import time
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])

# Specify the Chrome profile directory to use (Profile 2)
options.add_argument('--profile-directory=Profile 2')

# Specify the user data directory where Chrome profile data is stored
options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\PC\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
# the website to load
driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/")

time.sleep(5)
```

Things to note:

**Ensure Chrome is Closed**:

- Make sure that all instances of Chrome are closed before running your Selenium script. Sometimes, if Chrome is running in the background or doesn't shut down correctly, it can cause issues when trying to start a new instance.

**Check ChromeDriver Version**:

- Ensure that your ChromeDriver version matches the version of Google Chrome installed on your system. If they don't match, it can lead to compatibility issues.

Demo:

[image]